# Using Tkinter to program an application need add buttons with same function. How to identify which button I clicked and change the line automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following things I want is to add multiple different tasks, and there is a task start button which is used to trig a timer.

```
class Pomodoro_app(Tk):
    def add_task(self):
        global time
        time = StringVar()
        time.set("Start")
        task_content = askstring(title = 'Add a Task', prompt = "Input a task")
        task_label   = Label(self, text = task_content, font = ("Arial, 12")).grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        task_start_button = Button(self, textvariable = time, command = self.start_working).grid(column = 1, row = 3)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.welcome_label   = Label(self, text = "Welcome to the Challenge!", font = ("Arial, 12")).grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.add_task_button = Button(self, text = "Add Task", width = 20, command = self.add_task).grid(column = 0 , columnspan = 2)

    def __init__(self):
        """GUI Initiation"""
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.createWidgets()
        """window Initiation"""
        self.resizable(False, False)
        x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
        y = (self.winfo_screenheight() - self.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
        self.geometry('250x400+%d+%d' % (x, y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lambda (or inner function), you can pass additional argument to callback.

For example:

```
class Pomodoro_app(Tk):
    def add_task(self):
        global time
        time = StringVar()
        time.set("Start")
        task_content = askstring(title = 'Add a Task', prompt = "Input a task")
        task_label   = Label(self, text = task_content, font = ("Arial, 12")).grid(column = 0, row = self.next_row)
        task_start_button = Button(self, textvariable = time, command = lambda: self.start_working(task_content)).grid(column = 1, row = self.next_row)
        #                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.next_row += 1

    def start_working(self, task_name):
        print('start working', task_name)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.welcome_label   = Label(self, text = "Welcome to the Challenge!", font = ("Arial, 12")).grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.add_task_button = Button(self, text = "Add Task", width = 20, command = self.add_task).grid(column = 0 , columnspan = 2)

    def __init__(self):
        """GUI Initiation"""
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.createWidgets()
        """window Initiation"""
        self.resizable(False, False)
        x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
        y = (self.winfo_screenheight() - self.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
        self.geometry('250x400+%d+%d' % (x, y))
        self.next_row = 3
```

Comment: Thanks budy, I am now trying to figure out how contain it with thread. There is a timer will change the text on the task_start_button.

Comment: @JakeYang, How about post a separated questioni about that?

Comment: I am considering that. I would like to do it first and if I can't really solve it, I will post out.